# How do I disable drivers check after login in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: kubuntu, startup, dbus

Every time I login after full system restart I see running process "DriverManager" (can't give full description because it's happen for short amount of time), this is annoying because of high CPU usage (python?). How do I disable it?

Currently I have changed line in `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kubuntu.DriverManager.service` from

`Name=org.kubuntu.DriverManager`

to

`Name=org.kubuntu.DriverManager.disabled`

This prevent this process from run on startup, but also broke «Driver Manager». Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: nope, I didn't :(

Answer (score 0):

I've been suffering from the same problem. Searching for a solution I've found your question and also this bug report at Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-driver-manager/+bug/1304598 .

I've entered the Device Manager in the System Settings, as someone suggests there, but it hasn't worked. I've entered again and have it let run until the end, until it has informed me that there wasn't any private driver. Now the Device Manager has stopped running after every login.

So the solution seems to let the Driver Manager run at least one time, until the end of the check. I hope it works for you too.